# Calculate distance between two points from two lists

Tags: python, numpy, types, distance

```
B1, B2,B3
-232.34 -48.48 -260.77
-233.1 -49.48 -253.6
-232.44 -50.81 -250.25
-233.02 -51.42 -248.88
-232.47 -51.95 -248.06
-232.17 -52.25 -247.59
-232.6 -52.83 -245.82
-232.29 -53.63 -243.98
-231.65 -53.24 -243.76

o1,o2,o3
-302.07 -1.73 -280.1
-302.13 -3.37 -273.02
-303.13 -4.92 -269.74
-302.69 -4.85 -268.32
-303.03 -5.61 -267.45
-302.55 -5.2 -267.22
-302.6 -5.91 -266.01
-302.46 -6.41 -264.79
-302.59 -7.4 -264.96







import numpy as np
# Convert your arrays to numpy arrays
B1 = np.asarray(B1)
B2 = np.asarray(B2)
B3 = np.asarray(B3)
o1 = np.asarray(o1)
o2 = np.asarray(o2)
o3 = np.asarray(o3)
# Find the distance in a single, vectorized operation
force = np.sqrt(np.sum(((B1-o1)**2, (B2-o2)**2, (B3-o3)**2), axis=0))
print(force)
print(B1,B2,B3,o1,o2,o3)
#87.08173861378742 is the result of force
#-231.65 -53.24 -243.76 -302.59 -7.4 -264.96 is the result for 
B1,B2,B3,o1,o2,o3
#the code only uses last data set for the force calculation. It should use
```

all the data

```
The data type of B1-o3 changed from 
 <class 'numpy.float64'> to <class 'numpy.ndarray'> after the code runs.
```

I wan to calculate the distances between the two point (O and B). each points comes from 3D system. I think there is something wrong about my data type, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Instead of that first block of code (everything above `import numpy as np`), could you just post the `np.arrays` you get after converting? It's hard to tell what your data is actually like

Comment: revised. I am so confused now

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://ideone.com/RRSmqR).

Comment: Your B1 is not actually an array. It contains just one number. You need to pass list like argument

Comment: [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676714/10077) [also works](https://ideone.com/NYDoqB).

Answer (score 0):

```
B1=np.array([-232.34 ,-233.1])
B2=np.array([ -48.48,-49.48 ])
B3=np.array([ -260.77,-253.6 ])
O1=np.array([-302.07 ,-302.13])
O2=np.array([-1.73 ,-280.1])
O3=np.array([-1.73 ,-273.02])
```

Providing `axis=1` will enforce what you need

```
force = np.sqrt(np.sum(((B1-O1)**2, (B2-O2)**2, (B3-O3)**2), axis=1))
print(force)
[ 98.11938544 235.3107454  259.76693015]
```

Comment: Is there any way we dont have to put numbers in the np.array()?

Comment: It is the list of number or Series if you are have Pandas background

Answer (score 0):

I put those two tables into two text files. table_B.txt and table_o.txt

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('table_B.txt',sep = ' ',header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('table_o.txt',sep = ' ',header=None)

x = (df1[0] - df2[0])**2 + (df1[1] - df2[1])**2 + (df1[2] - df2[2])**2
x**.5

0    86.148037
1    85.254967
2    86.503343
3    86.026667
4    86.614556
5    86.904452
6    86.655193
7    87.101168
8    87.081739
dtype: float64
```

Is this what you wanted? I read each table into a pandas dataframe. Then squared the difference between the rows in df1 and df2. I then added all the columns together and took the square root.

You end up with a Series of distances for each row.